# use regex validator to ensure a string contains particular substring

Tags: regex, asp.net-mvc-3

I want to use a regex validator to ensure that a certain string variable contains the substring `"www.youtube.com/watch?v="`, how would I do this?

```
[RegularExpression()]
[Required(ErrorMessage = "Youtube link is Required")]
[StringLength(100, ErrorMessage="Youtube link cannot exceed 50 characters")]
public string YoutubeLink { get; set; }
```

Comment: what language do you want the answer for?  Also, there are plenty of resources out there that show how to use regex to do this

Comment: From your code it looks like we are talking about c# (correct me if I'm wrong (and maybe add an apropreiate tag). In this case: Why would you need a regex for this? `YoutubeLink.Contains("www.youtube.com/watch?v=")` will return whether the substring is contained in `YoutubeLink` or not. If I was wrong about the language I would still guess that such a method would exist

Answer (score 4):

```
if (YoutubeLink.Contains("www.youtube.com/watch?v="))
{
   //...
}
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dy85x1sa.aspx

To use the RegularExpression attribute, you must specify the regex to use :

```
[RegularExpression("www\\.youtube\\.com/watch\\?v=", ErrorMessage = "Link is incorrect")]
public string YoutubeLink { get; set; }
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.regularexpressionattribute.aspx

---

I think what you might want is to check for any type of URL beginning. In that case, you would use `@"^(http://)?(www\.)?youtube\.com/watch\?v="` as the regex string.

[See an example of what this would match](http://regexpal.com/?flags=m&regex=%5E%28http%3A%2F%2F%29%3F%28www%5C.%29%3Fyoutube%5C.com%2Fwatch%5C%3Fv%3D&input=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.youtube.com%2Fwatch%3Fv%3D12323456%0D%0A%0D%0Ahttp%3A%2F%2Fyoutube.com%2Fwatch%3Fv%3D12323456%0D%0A%0D%0Awww.youtube.com%2Fwatch%3Fv%3D12323456%0D%0A%0D%0Ayoutube.com%2Fwatch%3Fv%3D12323456%0D%0A%0D%0Ahttp%3A%2F%2Fwww.goingbananas.com%0D%0A%0D%0Awww.goingbananas.com%0D%0A%0D%0Ahttp%3A%2F%2Fgoingbananas.com%0D%0A%0D%0Agoingbananas.com)

Comment: I would like to use the [RegularExpression()] validator though

Comment: @ibiza: You *should* quote the `.`s, and you **must** quote the `?`: `@"www\.youtube\.com/watch\?v="`.

Comment: sorry I ment to check if the string starts with www.youtube.com/watch?v= not if it is the same

Comment: a regular expression will find a match if the regex is found within a string...it has not to be the same as the whole string. If you want to check if it *starts* with www. and so on, you would need to add a caret (^) at the beginning of the regex, but then it wouldn't return a match for an url starting with http://, are you sure you want that the link absolutely need to begin with www?

Comment: the bottom line is, I need to check whether my string begins with "http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=" without the quotation marks  p.s. stackoverflow removes the h t t p:// turnes it into a link

Comment: formulated as is ( I need ... BEGINS with), then use `^http://youtube\.com/watch\?v=` for the regex. But this won't match URLs using www. in it.

Comment: @AlanBudzinski: Your string is getting interpreted by the StackOverflow software as a link, and therefore processed in such a way that we can't see exactly what it looks like. You need to wrap it in the backquote character, `, to tell the software to treat your string as source-code.

Comment: `[RegularExpression("^(http://)?(www\\.)?youtube\\.com/watch\\?v=", ErrorMessage = "Youtube link must start with http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=")]` this is my code, it only works when my string is exactly like this: `http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=` but when I have additional characters after the ?v= it gives me validation error/message

Answer (score -1):

Maybe much easier to use something like (Python):

```
ytlink  = 'www.youtube.com/watch?v='
if(ytlink in yourfrase):
  doYourLogic()
else:
  smthElse()
```

Please correct me if I understood your question wrong.