# regular expression string starts with a letter in mvc

Tags: regex, asp.net-mvc, validation, model

i am trying to validate if string starts with letter k, followed by anything

Expected output :

```
khtjk
k1234
kq12g
```

i followed [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1240504/regular-expression-to-match-string-starting-with-stop) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8348561/use-regex-validator-to-ensure-a-string-contains-particular-substring), but it doesnt allow anything after k

this is what i tried :

```
[RegularExpression("^k", ErrorMessage = "Sorry, enter correct bill no")]
public string StoreBillNo { get; set; }
```

any help would be great.

Comment: @Avinash Raj, thank you that works fine, but to check  both capital  and small k, post as answer if required

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to use this regex for capital and small case:

```
^[kK].*
```

or use ignore case :

```
/^k.*/i
```

OR

```
"(?i)^k.*"
```

Comment: thank you works great, stackoveflow, wants me to wait for 2 minutes to accept your answer, just waiting, 33 seconds more

Comment: oh you copied my answer. For case-insesitivity, you could use `(?i)` modifier at the start also.

Comment: @AvinashRaj it is the simplest regex that OP needed so there's no need to copy but yes you put it as comment so you think that i copied..:)

Comment: @EhsanSajjad no probs :), asked just for fun :-)

Comment: @AvinashRaj FYI just telling you that i also got interetsed to learn regex so i strated to look in regex tag questions ..:)

Comment: keep up the good work.. Try to post regex answers on very first. Because  there are many regex gurus here.

Comment: hi, both , for ignore case  i tried these three,  `/^k.*/i` and `/^k.*/?i` and this `(?i)^k.*`, but doesn't work

Comment: @stom first one is fine as it is just one letter so you can afford to add captial and small both

Comment: yes first one works fine, it was simple, i tried, but failed, but now with your help i could learn and do,  thanking both of you for guiding thus far